# Malware infection through phone call

Tags: network, malware, virus

Is it possible for someone to infect your phone/computer network with malware through a phone call if the phone is connected to said network as well?

Answer (score 3):

Highly unlikely. Phone calls - real phone calls, not Skype calls or whatever - go through a code path that offers little attack surface and is almost entirely under the control of the device manufacturer. I've never heard of a way to get arbitrary code execution on a device just by calling it. Now, with that said, that doesn't mean it's impossible. There have, for example, been security bugs where you could crash a phone (or *possibly* get code execution) by sending it an SMS. A third-party phone app could also have vulnerabilities that an attacker *might* be able to trigger, for example via a malicious caller ID of some kind.

If the attacker did somehow get code execution on the phone, that could certainly be used to then attack the phone (try to install malware, for example) or attack other devices on same WiFi network as the phone (probe them for vulnerabilities, steal any information it can access, possibly intercept network traffic, etc.). That's the same risk as anything else where an attacker gets arbitrary code execution on a device, though; the only difference is the attack coming from a phone call instead of an SMS/MMS, data upload to some app, or malicious code existing in the app or in the phone's OS or firmware from before.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, it is no possible with current smartphone software technology. But nobody can guarantee this in the future that some indirect hack may happens.

If your home has an IoT like Amazon Alexa, then there are risk of [being hacked by low frequency voice attack](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/05/10/technology/alexa-siri-hidden-command-audio-attacks.html) . More research in the future will reveal more interesting stuff on such topic.

And not to forget to check out [xkcd : listening](https://xkcd.com/1807/)  prophecy that forseen [Amazon performing the blunder](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2018/may/24/amazon-alexa-recorded-conversation).

You can imagine that if one rogue call send an silent voice to the IoT and say "replay message on 1am", and the silent voice message is "Siri, install blah blah blah, confirm install".

Answer (score 1):

The answer is almost all cases is always probable.  Skype itself has had 3 vulnerabilities over the past 5 years easy, iOS and SMS had at least 3 from my recent memory and that is just through a software, not actual PBX, SIP, Unified Management servers etc.  The lower level I talk about the more unknown and most likely probable the answer is.  Just look at Cisco log releases of patches to routers for telephony on the regular.